# PDO::bindParam/bindValue creates the wrong parameter type

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have a stored procedure that takes some integer parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[redacted_name]
    @CustomerID int , 
    @ContactPersonID int,
    @ChangeContactPersonId int = null,
    @Name varchar(50)  = NULL
    -- snip
AS
BEGIN
  -- snip
END
```

I'm using the following code to call this stored procedure:

```
$db = $this->db();
$statement = $db->prepare("exec dbo.redacted_name @CustomerId=?,@ContactPersonId=?");

$statement->bindValue(1, 73, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(2, 42, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
//snip
```

Which generates the following SQL, grabbed from a profiler:

```
declare @p1 int
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 TEXT,@P2 TEXT',N'exec dbo.redacted_name  @customerId=@P1,@contactPersonId=@P2','73','42'
select @p1
exec sp_unprepare @p1
go
```

Executing this SQL, causes the following error on Microsoft Sql Server 11.0.5343:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure redacted_name , Line 0
>   Operand type clash: text is incompatible with int

Which makes some sense, because `TEXT != INT` Considering I specifically told PDO that I'm passing an `INT`, why does PDO generate two `TEXT` variables? And what can I do to work around it?

Comment: have you tried with bindParam()?

Comment: @Robert Yes. Same problem. I posted the question with `bindValue` because that makes the code slightly shorter (no variables required).

Comment: There are "driver options" argument for BindParam() maybe it would help

Comment: @Robert I had missed those. After looking into it, that's a can of worms we're not in a position to open at this time. We're hosting the application on Linux (RHEL 7), and it took about two man weeks to be able to communicate with the database at all. The driver options argument in our case requires MS-specific drivers, which exist for RHEL5 and RHEL6. I do feel like that's the solution, though.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, so maybe I'l lpost my comment as answer so the quetsion can be closed?

Comment: @Robert sorry for the late reply. We have installed the MS-specific drivers anyway due to an unrelated issue with the drivers we were using. Without driver options, they have the same problem. I have not yet been able to test with driver options, because we haven't compiled the extension that has the constants into PHP. You can (and probably should) post your suggestion as an answer, but I cannot accept it until I've verified that it works. Meanwhile we've been using a workaround that I will post as an answer, but will also not accept because it's horrible.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to investigate on "driver options" argument for BindParam() maybe it would help.

There are some cases where it may be the problem.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a way to compile MSSQL-specific options into PHP on Linux. =[

Answer (score 1):

Today I get same kind of issue. I got something like : 
Invalid character value for cast specification: 206 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Operand type clash: text is incompatible with int.

I use PHP 7.0 with PDO with Microsoft ODBC on Linux CentOS 7 with a connection string like :

```
$pdo = new PDO('odbc:driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;server=MyServer;database=MyDB;MARS_Connection=yes', 'user', 'pass');
```

To fix the issue, exact Stored proc param case is required.

Stored proc param @CustomerID int is defined with "ID" then you must use @CustomerID = ? and not @CustomerId = ?...

```
$statement = $db->prepare("exec dbo.redacted_name @CustomerID=?, @ContactPersonID=?");
```

Look like the driver try to figure out the target type by looking at proc argument using case sensitive match.

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this question, thanks for adding an answer! Unfortunately, I have since changed employers, and thus have no way to verify if this would solve the issue in this particular project. I've relayed your answer to a former colleague, though. Have an upvote!